# EFCore.BulkExtensions fails to do insert with Guid PK

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sqlbulkcopy, ef-core-2.2

I am using EFCore.BulkExtensions to insert an entity with a GUID / UniqueIdentifier primary key into my database, but I am receiving the following exception when I call this line:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
>   given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to
>   type uniqueidentifier of the specified target column.
>   Source=EFCore.BulkExtensions   StackTrace:    at
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions.SqlBulkOperation.Insert[T](DbContext context,
>   IList`1 entities, TableInfo tableInfo, Action`1 progress)    at
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions.DbContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsert[T](DbContext
>   context, IList`1 entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig, Action`1 progress)
>   at
>   MyCompany.Abp.EfCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsert[TEntity,TPrimaryKey](IRepository`2
>   repository, IList`1 entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig, Action`1
>   progress) in
>   D:\Projects\MySystem\Utilities\MyCompany.Abp.EfCore\BulkExtensions.BulkInsert.cs:line
>   21    at
>   s.SearchServices.Infrastructure.UnscConsolidatedList.Infrastructure.s.MonitoringBatch.MonitoringBatchSearchJob.PerformScreening(Guid
>   sourceId, IList`1 Records) in
>   D:\Projects\MySystem\Modules\s\s.SearchServices.Infrastructure.UnscConsolidatedList\Infrastructure\s\MonitoringBatch\MonitoringBatchSearchJob.cs:line
>   96    at
>   s.SearchServices.Infrastructure.UnscConsolidatedList.Infrastructure.s.MonitoringBatch.MonitoringBatchSearchJob.ExecuteJob(MonitoringBatchSearhJobArgs
>   args) in
>   D:\Projects\MySystem\Modules\s\s.SearchServices.Infrastructure.UnscConsolidatedList\Infrastructure\s\MonitoringBatch\MonitoringBatchSearchJob.cs:line
>   82    at
>   s.SearchServices.Infrastructure.UnscConsolidatedList.Core.BatchSearchJobBase`1.Execute(TBatchSearhJobArgs
>   args) in
>   D:\Projects\MySystem\Modules\s\s.SearchServices.Infrastructure.UnscConsolidatedList\Core\BatchSearchJobBase.cs:line
>   28
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter
>   value from a String to a Guid.
>
> Inner Exception 2: InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from
>   'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.

The code that throws the exception:

```
        public static void BulkInsert<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>(
            this IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repository,
            IList<TEntity> entities,
            BulkConfig bulkConfig = null,
            Action<decimal> progress = null)
            where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
        {
            var db = repository.GetDbContext();
            db.BulkInsert(entities, bulkConfig, progress); // <== throws exception
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?